# Excel - Assigning 3 columns of numbers to equal 100%, Minus one column for absentees

Tags: excel-formula

So I am trying to calculate 3 columns of numbers (for a register) to equal 100% total and for the absentees to affect the overall percent attendance.

For Example:

```
A1=1
B1=1
D1=1


A1+B1+D1=100% - D1=67%
```

D1 is the absentees and needs to be subtracted from the overall 100%, so in this instance each value is 33.33% as there are three values in total. So A1+B1 would make 67%. How do I formulate this? The formula needs to be scalable (this section has three values but I also need it for four values). Any help will be appreciated.
[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNtXM.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula:

```
=((A1+B1+C1)/(A1+B1+C1+D1))*100
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that still gives a value of 100%. Thank you though! I need it to say 67%.

Comment: If you desire a rounded result, you can surround this formula with the  ROUND() function ( https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROUND-function-c018c5d8-40fb-4053-90b1-b3e7f61a213c )

Answer (score 0):

So, `(A1+B1+C1)/3*100` will give you the percentage result. You could refer to a cell for the 3 or 4 and if that is in D1 then `(A1+B1+C1)/$D$1*100`

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't calculate it properly. I've included an image for a reference.

Comment: It always equals 100% with that method and I need absentees to be taken away.

Comment: Sorry, don't follow your logic - d1 is an absence that you add to the total and then subtract? Why not just add the "present" values and divide by the total possible then convert to % as I suggested.